# A variant of geometric summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\beta^n \sum_{k=-10}^n \beta^{-k} = \frac{\beta^{n+11} - 1}{\beta- 1}$$

For the following series summation, I am not sure as to how the answer is derived. Is there something to do with the index switching?

Comment: Which formula do you have at hand?

Comment: Write $k\to k-10$ then apply the finite geometric sum.

Comment: Bring the $\beta^n$ inside, and let $j=n-k$. The series (backwards) is the sum of $\beta^j$ from $j=0$ to $j=n+10$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\beta^n\sum \beta^{-k}=\beta^n(\beta^{10}+\beta^{11}+\beta^{12}+...+\beta^{-n})=\\\beta^{n+10}+\beta^{n+11}+\beta^{n+12}+...+\beta^{n-n}=\\\beta^0 +\beta^1+...+\beta^{n+10}=\frac{1-\beta^{n+10+1}}{1-\beta}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\beta^n \sum_{k=-10}^n \beta^{\color{blue}{-k}} =\beta^\color{green}n \sum_{k=\color{blue}{-n}}^{\color{blue}{+10}} \beta^{\color{blue}k}= \sum_{k=\color{green}0}^{\color{green}n+10} \beta^{k}.$$